# Keras: data generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

- I saw this code to use the keras generator (*)
- but when I run "__data_generation", python complain about the asterix in "*self.dim" with the message "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Do you know if I should use the "asterix?"
- if I remove it and that I use only "self.dim" then I got an error message on the np creation "TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an index".
- Do you know to fix this issue? I'm using Python 2.7.5.

(*)

```
import numpy as np
import keras

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=10, dim=(32,32), n_channels=1, n_classes=10, shuffle=True):<br> 
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.labels = labels
    self.list_IDs = list_IDs
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
        # Store sample
        X[i,] = np.load('data/' + ID + '.npy')

        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `*self.dim` is used to unpack a container as argument. This basically means that you pass `self.dim` and the function treats it as a tuple to be unpacked inside the function. See [this](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558) for a broader explanation (section "For unpacking the containers").

In your case you are using it in:

```
X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
```

where `np.empty()` expects a tuple containing ints (or a single int) as first argument. In your case you are passing a tuple containing a tuple as a second element. You must unpack it yourself to make it work like:

```
X = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.dim[0], self.dim[1], self.n_channels))
```

So, you should stick with the `*` part but treat differently the argument. Also, the `*arg` possess more flexibility meaning it can deal with containers with 2, 3 etc elements will a hard-coded piece of code like `args[0], args[1]` does not have.